# Codename One - Transition from FormA to FormB to FormC

Tags: android, ios, codenameone

The following code works as expected on the Codename One simulator, that is:

- show first Form (startForm)
- fade to the second Form (emptyForm) for two seconds
- fade to the third Form for one second (loginForm)

So the transition duration should be three seconds in total.

But on real devices the third Form is shown almost immediately. What's wrong in my code?

```
// Transition from startForm to loginForm
startForm.show();
startForm.setTransitionOutAnimator(CommonTransitions.createFade(2000));
emptyForm.show();
emptyForm.setTransitionOutAnimator(CommonTransitions.createFade(1000));
UITimer.timer(2000, false, emptyForm, new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        loginForm.show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`show()` is non-blocking so calling it in sequence like this isn't a good idea. It could cut the transition time effect or even collide.

The way to accomplish this is:

```
startForm.addShowListener(e -> {
   emptyForm.addShowListener(ee -> loginForm.show());
   emptyForm.show();
});
```

Comment: I tested that the emptyForm.addShowListener() should be before the emptyForm.show() method, otherwise its ShowListener will never be called.

Comment: However, this solution doesn't work for me on real devices, because the CommonTransitions.createFade(2000) is simply ignored by real devices.

Comment: Which real device? Notice that startup time might impact the transition speed

Comment: Why? Is the startup time calculated in the transition speed? I accept your answer because your important hint of the "addShowListener", however the fading effect between simulator and real devices is different.

Comment: Yes, fade has always been surprisingly "challenging". We don't explicitly calculate startup time as we just don't know it. The OS calls the equivalent of the `start()` method before a UI is physically visible.