# Codename One - ReplaceAndWait() doesn't work?

Tags: android, ios, codenameone

This question is related to my previous question "[Codename One - Transition from FormA to FormB to FormC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47521900/codename-one-transition-from-forma-to-formb-to-formc)".

I've spent a lot of hours trying do to working transitions between Form, without success on real devices (on the simulator there are not problems). Finally, I've chosen to change the logic, replacing the transitions between three Form into replacing of three Containers inside the same Form. The idea is that the ReplaceAndWait() method ensures me that it waits the end of the replacing. BUT... also in this case, the code works well in the Codename One simulator (using Android and iOS skins) and doesn't work on real devices. To be more clear: there is no "fade effect" on real devices (tested on Android 4.x and 5.x). What's wrong in the following code?

```
        Container container1 = new Container(new BorderLayout(BorderLayout.CENTER_BEHAVIOR_SCALE));
        container1.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, FlowLayout.encloseCenterMiddle(myIcon));

        Container container2 = new Container(new BorderLayout(BorderLayout.CENTER_BEHAVIOR_SCALE));
        container2.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, FlowLayout.encloseCenterMiddle(new Label(" ")));

        Container container3 = new Container(new BorderLayout(BorderLayout.CENTER_BEHAVIOR_SCALE));
        container3.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, backgroundContainer);

        startForm.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, container1);
        startForm.show();

        container1.getParent().replaceAndWait(container1, container2, CommonTransitions.createFade(2000));
        container2.getParent().replaceAndWait(container2, container3, CommonTransitions.createFade(1000));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me on the device:

```
    Form f = new Form("Fade", new BorderLayout());

    Container container1 = BorderLayout.center(FlowLayout.encloseCenterMiddle(new Label(duke)));

    Container container2 = BorderLayout.center(FlowLayout.encloseCenterMiddle(new Label(" ")));

    Label redDuke = new Label(duke);
    redDuke.getUnselectedStyle().setBgColor(0xff0000);
    redDuke.getUnselectedStyle().setBgTransparency(255);

    Container container3 = BorderLayout.center(FlowLayout.encloseCenterMiddle(redDuke));

    f.add(CENTER, container1);
    f.show();

    callSerially(() -> {
        container1.getParent().replaceAndWait(container1, container2, CommonTransitions.createFade(2000));
        container2.getParent().replaceAndWait(container2, container3, CommonTransitions.createFade(1000));
    });
```

But not exactly in the way it worked on the simulator due to the different way fade works with on the device. For efficiencies sake fade is implemented a bit differently on devices and the simulator and some behaviors might render differently especially with translucent/transparent components.

Comment: Thanks. Your code doesn't work on my device: the first fade from container1 to container2 doesn't run at all (the first container is shown for two seconds without fading), the second fade works (but in a strange way, because the red background appears immediately and then the duke icon fades over it). Tested on Android 4.1.2

Comment: That's pretty much it. The transparency behavior in fade is problematic when we have translucent elements in place. How do you fade in transparency? Try doing the effect between elements of identical size with full opacity